# How we Get Wifi Current Protocol version (802.11n/b/g) of windows 10 from C#

Tags: c#, windows

I want to get the Wifi(W Lan) current Protocol (802.11n /b/ j)

I am trying to get this from c# code

**strong text**

I Expect to get Protocol:802.11n

Comment: Have you seen this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.wifi.wifiadapter and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.wifi.wifiphykind

Comment: Your question is not so clear. Maybe you should read this [tutorial about how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)